Why some site columns did not get managed properties while other for 2 managed properties
I got this weird behavior inside our site collection. now we have 3 site columns added to a custom list and they contain data:-

now the 3 site columns get automatic crawl properties, as follow:-

Ready Date:-


APPT Status:-


PU-ETA's:-



Then for the managed properties i only got managed properties for the "APPT Status" column & for the "PU-ETA", while the "Ready Date" did not get an automatic managed properties as follow:-

Ready Date, i did not get any managed property:-


APPT Status, i got 2 managed properties:-


PUET's, i got 2 managed properties:-



So I have those 2 questions:-

Why some site columns did not get managed properties? although the field have data inside the lists and the data were inside the lists for more than 2 weeks now.

For the other site columns why they got 2 managed properties such as those 2 managed properties for the PU-ETA's field (which have this internal name PUETAs) :-



PUETAsOWSDATE (without T)
PUETAsOWSTDATE (with T)

